# ¿Cómo evitar en la búsqueda salga %20 en los espacios?

Tags: php, busqueda

Hola compañeros espero puedan ayudarme, utilizo un script llamado "Videoflix" y en el mismo hay un buscador para encontrar el contenido del sitio.

El problema surge cuando se intenta utilizar dicho buscador ya que al realizar una búsqueda de una única palabra funciona perfectamente, sin embargo si se intenta realizar una consulta que tenga 2 o más palabras separadas por un espacio el buscador no encuentra nada y al parecer es porque remplaza los espacios con %20.

Estas son las lineas que están implicadas en el proceso de búsqueda.

Formulario:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?browse/search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulos, actores, generos" 
                    style="background-color: #000; border: 1px solid #808080;" name="search_key">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </form>
```

Browse.php

```
function search($search_key = '')
{
    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {
        $search_key = $this->input->post('search_key');
        redirect(base_url().'index.php?browse/search/'.$search_key , 'refresh');
    }
    $page_data['page_name']     =   'search';
    $page_data['search_key']    =   $search_key;
    $page_data['page_title']    =   'Search result';
    $this->load->view('frontend/index', $page_data);

}
```

Crud_model.php

```
    function get_search_result($type = '', $search_key = '')
{
    $this->db->like('title', $search_key);
    $query  =   $this->db->get($type);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Muestra de resultados search.php

```
    <?php
    $movies     =   $this->crud_model->get_search_result('movie' , $search_key);
    $series     =   $this->crud_model->get_search_result('series', $search_key);
    ?>
<div class="row" style="margin:20px 60px;">
    <h4>
        Resultados para : "<?php echo $search_key;?>"
    </h4>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="grid">
            <?php 
                foreach ($movies as $row)
                {
                    $title  =   $row['title'];
                    $link   =   base_url().'index.php?browse/playmovie/'.$row['movie_id'];
                    $thumb  =   $this->crud_model->get_thumb_url('movie' , $row['movie_id']);
                    include 'thumb.php';
                }

                foreach ($series as $row)
                {
                    $title  =   $row['title'];
                    $link   =   base_url().'index.php?browse/playseries/'.$row['series_id'];
                    $thumb  =   $this->crud_model->get_thumb_url('series' , $row['series_id']);
                    include 'thumb.php';
                }
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Espero estas lineas les ayuden a encontrar lo que yo no, porque soy nuevo en esto de PHP y me cuesta trabajo identificar el problema.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y en qué te afecta directamente que los espacios se escapen con %20? ¿Te truena alguna parte de tu código? ¿Te da algún error? ¿Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: Hola Fernando antes que nada gracias por contestar, si el problema es que el buscador no encuentra el contenido, por ejemplo si busco "harry" encuentra todo lo que tenga Harry en el nombre pero si pongo Harry Potter, no arroja ningún resultado aunque haya contenido que incluya las 2 palabras y en el resultado aparece "Resultados para: Harry%20Potter"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás teniendo problemas con las entidades HTML. Con `php` puedes revertir este efecto usando una función llamada `urldecode`. De acuerdo con la documentación oficial:

> Decodifica cualquier cifrado tipo %## en la cadena dada. Los símbolos ('+') son decodificados como el caracter espacio.

Puedes encontrar más información de más usos [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php)

Trata de aplicarlo justo en la parte de cuando lo envías a buscar:

```
function get_search_result($type = '', $search_key = '')
{
    $this->db->like('title', urldecode($search_key));
    $query  =   $this->db->get($type);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Si enviaste a buscar: Harry Potter lo que estás obteniendo por el momento es un `Harry%20Potter` pero al usar `urldecode` vas a obtener como resultado `Harry Potter`

Espero te haya servido.

Comment: Fernando me has salvado de verdad, en efecto esa solución funciona perfectamente, sigue apareciendo el %20 en la parte de 

Resultados para: Harry%20Potter

Pero el buscador ya encuentra el contenido, ahora me documentare bien sobre esa función y veré como quito el %20 pero ya más por un tema estético que por funcionalidad.

Reitero muchas gracias tu apoyo me sirvió bastante.

Comment: Qué bueno que te sirvió, si te ha solucionado tu problema, te invito a marcarla como tu respuesta correcta para que otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema puedan encontrarla más rápido. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes reemplazar todos los `%20` por espacios de la variable `$search_key`

```php
$search_key = str_replace('%20', ' ', $this->input->post('search_key'));
```

Comment: Pense que podía aplicar esta solución para la parte de:

`Resultados para : "<?php echo $search_key;?>"`

Pero no consigo que funcione, de cualquier forma agradezco tu ayuda :)